# HTTPClient await GetByteArrayAsync returns to unexpected code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpclient

I'm new to async calls and face an issue I can't find a solution for.

I have a class library I'm calling from a CRM software. The CRM application sends XML data at the beginning and it expects XML to be returned from the library if the screen data should be updated by the library.

In the library I'm calling a function and this functions calls another function and
the third function in that row is an async function with an await get call.
Here is an overview about the structure. When

```
       public string[] Function1(string sXmlDoc)
   {
   //...
   Function2(par1, par2);
   //Returns to here from Async Call in Function 3
   return xml;
   }

   public void Function2(string par1, string par2)
   {
   //...
   Function3(par3);
   //...
   }

   public await void Function3(string par3)
   {
   //...
   //When it arrives here it jumps back to the first function
   byte[] fileBytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
   //and after jumping back it comes back to here.
   //...
   }
```

I hope it is clear what I mean. The problem is that the jump back returns already the xml
string to the CRM application. But in that xml I need data from the async call.
How to achieve that ? Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot in advance
Michael

Comment: Your methods should return a `Task<T>` rather than `void`. So if `Function3` returns the byte array, it should return a `Task<byte[]>`. Then `Function2` awaits the `Task<byte[]>` returned from `Function3`, e.g. `byte[] fileBytes = await Function3(par3)`. A `Task` represents an operation which might not have finished yet: it might be in progress, or have completed with a result, or completed with an exception.

Comment: This: `public await void Function3(string par3)` shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Oh, and do you _really_ need to switch from sync to async APIs here? Would be better to "go async all the way" if ever possible.

Comment: Method should be async and any consuming methods will also need to be async as well, or if you want it synchronous, remove await and add .Result.